# Orthogonality of $A$'s columns in $(C + AA^t)A = \lambda A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

### Setup

Let $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ symmetric positive definite with simple eigenvalues. Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ with $m>n$ a matrix with normalized columns $\mathbf{a}_i, i=1,...,m$:

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
|            &  |            &       &               | \\
|            &  |            &       &               | \\
|            &  |            &       &               | \\
\mathbf{a}_1 & \mathbf{a}_2  & \dots & \mathbf{a}_m    \\
|            &  |            &       &               | \\
|            &  |            &       &               | \\
|            &  |            &       &               | \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $\| \mathbf{a}_i \|_2 = 1, i=1,...,m$. Assume further $span\{\mathbf{a}_i\}_{i=1}^m = \mathbb{R}^n$ and
$$
(C + AA^t)A = \lambda A,
$$
so the columns of $A$ are eigenvectors of $C + AA^t$. One can see that $C$ and $AA^t$ have the same eigenvectors: since $AA^t = \lambda I - C$ every eigenvector of $C$ is an eigenvector of $\lambda I- C$, hence an eigenvector of $AA^t$.

### Question

Of course, we know the eigenvectors of $C$ are mutually orthogonal since $C$ only has simple eigenvalues. So, we ***may*** take the eigenvectors of $C + AA^t$ to be orthogonal. However, this may not hold for the columns of $A$. So: is it true that either $\mathbf{a}_i \perp \mathbf{a}_j$ or $\mathbf{a}_i || \mathbf{a}_j$ for any $i,j \in \{1,...,m \}$?

### My thoughts

Taking the (full) SVD, $A = U \Sigma V^t$. Then $AA^t = U \Sigma \Sigma^t U^t$. Hence $U$ diagonalizes $AA^t$, so it diagonalizes $C$ as well: since $C$ has simple eigenvalues, so does $AA^t$ - their sum is a scalar and the diagonalizaing basis is unique (up to signs). So if we let $C = UDU^t$, then the equation becomes
$$
(D + \Sigma\Sigma^t) \Sigma V^t = \lambda \Sigma V^t,
$$
with $V \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ orthogonal and $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ diagonal. This means the rows of $\Sigma V^t$ are orthogonal. I don't see any implication for $A$'s columns.

### One last detail

It might be useful to note that $AA^t = \sum_{i=1}^m \mathbf{a}_i \mathbf{a}_i^t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is (sadly) false. Here is a counter-example. Let $C =
diag( d_1,d_2), d_1 > d_2$. Denote

$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
  |     &     |   &   |     \\ 
  \mathbf{a}_1   &   \mathbf{a}_2   &   \mathbf{a}_3    \\
  |     &     |   &   |     \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Take $\mathbf{a}_1 = c_1e_1 + c_2e_2$, $\mathbf{a}_2 = -c_1e_1 + c_2e_2$ and $\mathbf{a}_3 =
e_1$. Then

$$
\mathbf{a}_1 \mathbf{a}_1^t = c_1^2e_1e_1^t + c_1c_2( e_1e_2^t + e_2e_1^t) +
c_2^2 e_2e_2^t,
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{a}_2 \mathbf{a}_2^t = c_1^2e_1e_1^t - c_1c_2( e_1e_2^t + e_2e_1^t) +
c_2^2 e_2e_2^t.
$$

Note that

$$
AA^t = \mathbf{a}_1 \mathbf{a}_1^t + \mathbf{a}_2\mathbf{a}_2^t + \mathbf{a}_3\mathbf{a}_3^t = (2c_1^2+1) e_1e_1^t + 2c_2^2e_2e_2^t, 
$$

a diaonal matrix. In order to make $C + AA^t$ a scalar matrix, we
need to make sure that $d_1 + 2c_1^2 + 1= d_2 + 2c_2^2 $, under the
constraint $c_1^2 + c_2^2 = 1$ (arises from the restriction $\| \mathbf{a}_i \|
= 1$). Substitute $c_2^2 = 1 - c_1^2$.

$$
d_1 + 2c_1^2 + 1= d_2 + 2 -2c_1^2 
$$

So

$$
c_1^2 = \frac{d_2 - d_1 + 1}{4}.
$$

In order to make $\mathbf{a}_1 \perp \mathbf{a}_2$ we need $c_1^2 = c_2^2 = \frac{1}{2}$
and unless we are lucky enough (specifically, $d_1 = d_2 +
\frac{1}{2}$), this will not be possible. For $\mathbf{a}_1 || \mathbf{a}_2$ to hold, we
need $c_1 = 0$ (requires $d_1-d_2 = 1$) or $c_1 = 1$ (impossible: it
requires $d_2 -d_1 = 3$, but $d_1 > d_2$).

So unless we are super lucky with $C$, the claim I made in the
question is false.